# radare2 difference between function offset and minbound

Tags: radare2

I am trying to understand the difference between a function's `offset` and its `minbound` in radare2. Consider this function in radare2 (output of `aflj`):

```
    {
        "offset": 4549740,
        "name": "sym.tightdb::TableViewBase::sync_distinct_view_unsignedlong",
        "size": 2394,
        "realsz": 4598,
        "stackframe": 1200,
        "calltype": "(null)",
        "cost": 4425,
        "cc": 103,
        "bits": 16,
        "type": "fcn",
        "nbbs": 213,
        "edges": 298,
        "ebbs": 9,
        "minbound": "4267940",
        "maxbound": "4552134",
        ...
    }
```

There are a few things which are not clear:

When I do `pdf @4549740` (print function at `offset`), radare2 starts to print at `0x456644` (=`4548164`), which is none of the values above.

I would expect that `offset` always points to the begin of the function's first basic block. Indeed, this seems to be the case here, as `offset` + `realsize` = `maxbound`. But `maxbound - minbound = 284194` and this is clearly much longer than the function should be.

So, what does `minbound` indicate and how does it differ from `offset`?

[Example binary](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SEk4raES0tpMLxrJfhUVmwuTaGJkQskK/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: `offset` should point to the begin of the function. Can you share the binary?

Comment: Sure. Added it above.

Comment: It indeed seems like a bug. I'd suggest you open an issue in the radare2 repository https://github.com/radare/radare2/issues/new

Comment: Thank you, I filed an issue: https://github.com/radare/radare2/issues/12065